# Redux form not initialized with clean value for a field

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have an array with period values that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    description: null,
    outdated: null,
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    description: null,
    outdated: null,
   },
]
```

I am building a redux form based on the selected period from this array. So, a user can choose which period he wants and the form will be built with initial values from the selected period. When the values are null like shown above and I do some changes and save the first period with some values, the form rebuilds with new initial values for the second period. And the initial values look right:

```
 initial: { 
    id: 2,
    description: null,
    outdated: null,
   },
```

But, in the form, the field `description` is rendered with the value from the first period.
This is the form:

```
    <Row>
      <Column md="6">
        <TextAreaField
          name="description"
          maxLength={1500}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          id="outdatedDescription"
        />
      </Column>
      <Column md="6">
        <Undertext><FormattedMessage id="RadioGroup.Outdated" /></Undertext>
        <VerticalSpacer eightPx />
        <RadioGroupField
          validate={[required]}
          name="outdated"
          direction="vertical"
          readOnly={readOnly}
          onChange={this.resetFields}
        >
          <RadioOption
            label={<FormattedMessage id="RadioOption.Outdated" />}
            value={outdatedCodes.YES}
          />
          <RadioOption
            label={<FormattedMessage id="RadioOption.NotOutdated" />}
            value={outdatedCodes.NO}
          />
        </RadioGroupField>
      </Column>
    </Row>
    <VerticalSpacer twentyPx />
    <FlexRow>
      <FlexColumn>
        <MainButton
          mini
          htmlType="button"
          onClick={formProps.handleSubmit}
          disabled={formProps.pristine}
        >
          <FormattedMessage id="Update" />
        </MainButton>
      </FlexColumn>
    </FlexRow>
```

Why when I check the redux state intial values are correct and the radio button value is correctly rendered, but the `description` field is rendered with the value from the previous period?
The user can select for which period he wants the form by selecting one of them on the timeline. If I do changes on the first period the second period is automatically selected for him, and then this error occures. If I select the period again manually on the timeline, then the `description` field doesn't show anything for the second period, like it is suppose to.
This is the function that I use for saving the data for each period, after which I automatically move to the next period which leads to the error.

```
updateActivity(values) {
    const { periods } = this.props;

    const otherThanUpdated = periods .filter(o => o.id !== values.id);
this.setSelectedPeriod(otherThanUpdated || undefined);
  }
```

And this is the select handler for when the user selects period manually on the timeline:

```
selectHandler(eventProps) {
    const { periods } = this.props;
    const { selectedItem: currentSelectedItem } = this.state;
    const selectedItem = periods.find(item => item.id === eventProps.items[0]);
    if (currentSelectedItem) {
      this.setState({ selectedItem: undefined });
      this.setSelectedPeriod(selectedItem);
    } else {
      this.setSelectedPeriod(selectedItem);
    }
    eventProps.event.preventDefault();
  }
```

I have configured the form to enable reinitialization:

```
enableReinitialize: true
```

I am not sure why is this `description` field rendered with the value from a previous period?

I am wondering if that has anything to do with how I build this component. In my parent component, I am sending props data to form component like this:

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
      selectedItemData: selectedItem,
      cancelSelectedActivity: this.cancelSelectedActivity,
      updateActivity: this.updateActivity,
    }));
```

And in my form component I don't have any local state, I am just building the intitial values with the prop `selectedItemData`:

```
const buildInitalValues = selectedItemData => ({ ...selectedItemData });
const mapStateToProps = (state, initialProps) => ({
  initialValues: buildInitalValues(initialProps.selectedItemData),
  onSubmit: values => initialProps.updateActivity(transformValues(initialProps.selectedItemData, values)),
});
```

Comment: How are you configuring the `reduxForm` ? if you have `keepDirtyOnReinitialize` by passing `description: null`, whatever you typed in the field will remain. You might want to try passing `description: ''` to override the field value

Comment: I am configuring the redux form with ```enableReinitialize: true```, I will try also with setting the description to empty string if it is ```null``` maybe that will force it to rerender the field.